# Distribution of pairwise differences

Tags: probability

Say I sample data pairs {x,y} from a normal random variable with known mean and variance. What is the limiting distribution of |x-y|? [with what mean and variance?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the samples are drawn independently from the same normally distributed random variable, then $X_1-X_2$ has a normal distribution with zero mean and twice the variance.

The absolute value  $|X_1-X_2|$ therefore has a [half-normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution)